How to evaluate a string as tcl command
I'm using Foundry Nuke and try to work with tcl command.
I have this code :
[lindex [split "xx_cc" "_"] 0]

If I put this code into a text node. I will output the correct result which is 'xx'
But in this case I put the code in the project setting (root) as a string . I added a new knob (named as 'cxproject' and type is text input knob). Then put the code in this knob ( as string)
Then in the a text node , I put this code :
[value root.cxproject]

Trying to load the code and evaluate that string to be executed as tcl command.
The result is the original string of the code itself -> [lindex [split "xx_cc" "_"] 0] . This is not what I want. I want to see the result as 'xx'.
I tried :
[eval [value root.cxproject] ]

but not working.
How to evaluate a string as tcl command using tcl script ?


Using eval $string is exactly what you should do.
Can you please share exactly what [value root.cxproject] returns?
It might be possible that you have too many square brackets.
For example:
eval {expr 1+1}   will return 2.
but eval [expr 1+1] will yield the error message invalid command name "2"

Thanks for the answer. Please check my post , I have just added new screen capture to explain the setup. I use additional brackets -> [eval [...] ] otherwise the 'eval' will be treated as a static string.

I know a lot about Tcl, but I'm not familiar with Nuke and the concepts of knobs and nodes.   I looked through https://www.nukepedia.com/reference/Tcl/group__tcl__builtin.html and see that the value command will expand brackets and dollar signs inside string knobs.   However, I don't know what a text node is exactly.
There might be some security setting applied to prevent text from getting evaluated, in order to prevent something bad.

I found the problem. There are 2 type of string knob : StringKnob and EvalString Knob. They look the same but EvalString will evaluate the script. In this case I 've used the String type - I should use EvalString  so the code will be evaluated and generate the output rather than the code itself. Now , the [value root.cxproject] will give me the correct 'xx'.
